# Remove the blank lines in a text file

Tags: string-manipulation, text

In a text file, there are several blank lines and how to remove all of them in a simple way ?

```
  str="adf{adfadfsa

       dddd sdf sdf,
       dfdsf


       dfsfda


       |df"
```

After done,

```
  res="adf{adfadfsa
       dddd sdf sdf,
       dfdsf
       dfsfda
       |df"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement rule `"\n" .. -> "\n"` will do it, where `"\n"..` means one or more new lines.

```
str = "adf{adfadfsa

         dddd sdf sdf,
         dfdsf


         dfsfda


         |df";

StringReplace[str, "\n" .. -> "\n"]
```

> `"adf{adfadfsa
>          dddd sdf sdf,
>          dfdsf
>          dfsfda
>          |df"`

The same with regular expressions:

```
StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["\n+"] -> "\n"]
```

Yet another way:

```
StringRiffle[StringSplit[str, "\n" ..], "\n"]
```

And also:

```
ExportString[DeleteCases[ImportString[str, "Lines"], ""], "Lines"]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I find Tab includes in my text, so StringReplace[str, "\n\t" .. -> "\n"] works.